# Multiple Symfony2 Sites using APC Cache

Tags: symfony, apc

I have two sites using the Symfony2 framework that have similar files.

The sites are both on the same server and use APC cache.

I have noticed that some items that are on one site are then used on another site.

Any APC that has been used have different and unique keys.

Is there some way of splitting the APC cache for each site or set a prefix or something?

Comment: I guess you could run each site in a different php-fpm instance.

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have FPM setup on our server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to use [`ApcUniversalClassLoader()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/ApcUniversalClassLoader.php)?

According to [manual](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/performance.html#use-an-autoloader-that-caches-e-g-apcuniversalclassloader), in your `autoload.php` you can boot APC with different keys:

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/ApcUniversalClassLoader.php';

$loader = new ApcUniversalClassLoader('your_application_key');
```

Cheers ;)

Comment: That is brilliant! That sorted it for me. Thanks for the answer and sorry for the late reply.