# Symfony2 - How to set Doctrine APC cache prefix with multiple apps

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm

***Update: See bottom of post***
( this was orginially posted when we were using SF 2.3, we're now on 2.7.0 )

We've got multiple Symfony apps running on our server, but we appear to be getting cache pollution across the sites due to all the doctrine ORM cache entries being prefixed with 'sf2'.

From spending the last 30 mins googing around, there doesn't appear to be an easy solution.

The first ones suggested using the ProjectConfiguration.class.php - but that appears to be a Symfony 1 thing.

The next possible solution was to use the ApcUniversalClassLoader class (as per this question on SO: [Multiple Symfony2 Sites using APC Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395298/multiple-symfony2-sites-using-apc-cache)).

The problem is that our setup uses composer to autoload, so we can't simply use the code as per that example.

The class caching side of APC is fine, you can set the key in the front controller, but it doesn't set the key for the doctrine cache.

Has anyone got any thoughts please as currently we're having to disable APC for doctrine on all but the first app.

Frontcontroller:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcClassLoader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';

// Use APC for autoloading to improve performance.
// Change 'sf2' to a unique prefix in order to prevent cache key    conflicts
// with other applications also using APC.
$loader = new ApcClassLoader('app_1', $loader);
$loader->register(true);

require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();

// wrap the default AppKernel with the AppCache one
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';
$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);

Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

-- Clarify --
Just to clarify, the code above refers the APC cache for the classes, this works as above and is fine. what we can't seem to change is the default namespaces for the doctrine ORM APC entries, these seem to be fixed and thus clash with each running instance.

-- Update --

After trying Zerrvox's suggestion of setting the namespace, it didn't seem to work, the main caches are still using the default namespaces. It wouldn't be so bad if they were randomly generated when the cache was cleared, but the default namespaces are the same on both my vagrant box and the live box and the caches were generated on the separate boxes, so its obviously not random.

These methods in the appProdProjectContainer class in the cache still refer to the default namespaces.

```
protected function getDoctrineCache_Providers_Doctrine_Orm_DefaultMetadataCacheService()
{
....        
$instance->setNamespace('sf2orm_default_9e755ef08ba52b507455ecd06d0a648985c9593b15aca1522b4725acaaf77ce6');
        return $instance;
}

// Same for...

protected function getDoctrineCache_Providers_Doctrine_Orm_DefaultQueryCacheService   

protected function getDoctrineCache_Providers_Doctrine_Orm_DefaultResultCacheService
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't specify if you are talking about doctrine ORM cache or annotation cache using Doctrine Annotations.

Anyway you can create your own APC cache service which can be used for both by defining a service in Symfony like this (yml)

```
   app.doctrine.apc_cache:
       class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache
       calls:
           - [setNamespace, ["app_namespace"]]
```

-- Update --

Did you specify the defined service as metadata cache for doctrine. See the configuration reference for the Doctrine bundle configuration http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#caching-drivers

```
   doctrine:
       orm:
           metadata_cache_driver:
               type: service
               id: app.doctrine.apc_cache
```

Comment: Sorry - yeah, I meant both really, any Doctrine cache at all. That said, do the annotations get cached with a key related to the path of the file they're in - similar to the way the class caches do? If so, they'd already be unique anyway as the two symfony installs are in different directories.

Anyway, I'll give your solution a try and update afterwards. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Zerrvox - see updated post, I can't post what I need to in a comment.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include how to configure doctrine to use the caching service

Comment: Ah cheers - no I didn't! Out of interest, is there anyway to set this at 'run time' instead of configs? We switch the db when the page is loaded, so we can run multiple sites off one code install so if possible, we could switch or setup the cache at the same time.

Comment: I guess you could just get the cache driver from the container and call setNamespace("dynamic_namespace"). This should work, but if you are not using different source code then there should be no need to change the metadata cache. It might be relevant to change the doctrine result cache and if you are using it for other caching purposes.

Answer (score 1):

It works in my case (Symfony 2.8 - 3.4):

```
doctrine_cache:
    providers:
        my_redis:
            type: redis
            namespace: "%prefix%"
            aliases:
              - redis_cache
```

Where "namespace" is prefix for given app setted up in parameters.yml